# How to force hard drive device number (linux)?

Tags: linux, hard-drive

When adding a new drive, it took over /dev/sda1. Now my old drive is /dev/sda2 and it messes with the current fstab setup of the server.
I know I can get away with using UUID or labels (what I just did), but I would still prefer having the primary drive take /dev/sda1...

So, how do I force a disk to take a particular device number?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way is to use UUIDs. Its is especilay important if you use multipath.

If you want to make /dev/sda be alvway specific drive, you will have to mess around with UDEV scripts. Personaly I think its not worth it.

There are some good QA on this site about how to use udev.

Comment: Don't forget `/dev/disk/by-id`

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the best way is to use UUIDs or labels as you have done, although you can use `by-path` to associate them by their interface.